# Sort by multiple fields together in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sorting

Let's say there are two fields `updatedAt` and `createdAt` in the document. However, the document doesn't necessarily have to have the `updatedAt` field if the document hasn't been updated yet.

I want to sort by both these fields, essentially merge the two fields into another field like `someField` and do

```js
    db.stuff.find({}, { sort: {`someField: -1 } });
```

What I am trying to say is that the current composition sort

```js
    db.stuff.find({}, {sort: { createdAt: -1, updatedAt: -1 } });
```

Will sort by createdAt first and then updatedAt.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the aggregation pipeline to create a conditional merge of the two fields with [`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [`$ifNull`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/).

```
db.stuff.aggregate([
  { $project:
    { createdOrUpdatedAt: { $ifNull: ["$updatedAt", "$createdAt"] },
      fieldA: 1,
      fieldB: 1,
      fieldEtc: 1 }
  },
  { $sort: { createdOrUpdatedAt: -1 } }
]);
```

Comment: is there anyway to do this without using aggregation?

Comment: As far as I know, there is not other than creating a new field and giving it the currentTime timestamp on document creation and document update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aggregation methods to sort, project, etc. If you're only looking for the following:

- sort my createdAt
- for all fields with the same createdAt, sort by the updatedAt

then the following will work:

```
db.stuff.aggregate(
   [
     { $sort : { createdAt : -1, updatedAt: -1 } }
   ]
)
```

I'm not sure why you'd need to merge the two fields into another field

Comment: I believe the OP wants to have a list of the items which have most recently been created or updated. So if some item was created yesterday, but edited 5 minutes ago, it should appear with the items that were created (or updated) 5 minutes ago, not the other items that were created around the same time yesterday.