# Sort data based on given id first

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Suppose I want to sort the data based on the current city first and then the remaining country data. Is there any way I achieve that in MongoDB?

Example

```
[
  { id: 2, name: 'sdf' },
  { id: 3, name: 'sfs' },
  { id: 3, name: 'aaa' },
  { id: 1, name: 'dsd' },
];
```

What I want as an outcome is the data with id 3 at first and the remaining other.
like

```
[
  { id: 3, name: 'sfs' },
  { id: 3, name: 'aaa' },
  { id: 1, name: 'dsd' },
  { id: 2, name: 'sdf' },
];
```

It's just a example,
My actual requirement is to sort the data based on certain category first and then the remaining one

Comment: look at this similar question [Sort by multiple fields together in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159128/sort-by-multiple-fields-together-in-mongodb)

Comment: My question is ,is it possible tot sort data base on some id like 3 first and append the remaining data after that

Comment: your question is not clear, please provide more details with example.

Comment: I have updated the question can you please have a look ?

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not.

Answer (score 1):

There is no straight way to sort condationaly in MongoDB, as per your example you can try aggregation query,

- `$facet` to separate result for both types of documents
- first, to get `id`: 3 documents
- second, to get `id` is not 3 documents and sort by `id` in ascending order
- `$project` and `$concatArrays` to concat both arrays in siquance
- `$unwind` deconstruct `all` array
- `$replaceRoot` to replace `all` object to root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      first: [
        { $match: { id: 3 } }
      ],
      second: [
        { $match: { id: { $ne: 3 } } },
        { $sort: { id: 1 } }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      all: { $concatArrays: ["$first", "$second"] }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$all" },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$all" } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/u3ogg9wBdZA)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible within mongodb but you could first fetch the documents from the db and then sort them in Javascript (or whatever other language you're using to present the data).

On a side note, having duplicate values in the "id" field is not a good practice and defies the definition of id itself.

Comment: It's just a example, 
My requirement is to sort the data based on certain category first and then the remaining one

Comment: @SagarGhimire Ok, so that "id" field would be more like something like "cat_id", so it makes sense for it to have duplicate values because it is not supposed to identify the document itself (as using "id" only might suggest). Anyway, aside from that detail, I think your best option here is to sort outside mongodb.